# Error al conectar a la base de datos de SQL desde eclipse - JasperSoft Studio

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jasper-reports

Cuando me conecto a la base de datos de `Sql Server 2008 R2` con la `autenticación de windows` desde el `Data Adapter Wizard` de `Report Design` en el mismo `eclipse - java`, me sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los datos con los que me conecto a la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el `Driver Classpath` coloqué el `sqljdbc42.jar` y me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se tiene que configurar algo en el mismo JasperSoft Studio?

Comment: Has probado en el JDBCUrl poner Integrated security = false ?

Parece como si no lo tuvieras configurado en el SQL

Igualmente, si lo quieres hacer con IntegratedSecurity revísate este enlace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx#Connectingintegrated

(Sacado de StackOverFlow inglés http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629718/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-integrated-security-with-the-jdbc-driver)

Comment: le coloqué false pero me dice error en usuario, pero no quiero conectarme por auntenticacion de Sql Server sino por autenticacion de windows